# How to prevent kubernetes pod (job) from being deleted automatically after completion

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I'm using two helm charts one for the config job and another for deployment.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
...
...
spec:
  backoffLimit: 1
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
...
...
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
...
```

The pod for the config job runs successfully and then the pod for the deployment is run.

I've noticed that pod for config job is deleted immediately after it is run.

How can I make sure the config job pod remains after run and is not deleted so I can debug them? Is there something I can set in the helm charts to prevent this? I need to do this so I can view the logs.

Comment: By any chance you using Hooks ? Then it is straight forward

Answer (score 0):

Use History Limits: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#jobs-history-limits

> The .spec.successfulJobsHistoryLimit and .spec.failedJobsHistoryLimit
> fields are optional. These fields specify how many completed and
> failed jobs should be kept. By default, they are set to 3 and 1
> respectively. Setting a limit to 0 corresponds to keeping none of the
> corresponding kind of jobs after they finish.

Comment: In a Kubernetes cluster, nodes are disposable. Eventually, there is no guarantee how long Completed or Errored pods would remain. While OP question indeed refers to history limits, we might add that: if you want to reliably find logs from a job, you should really forward those to some logging stack: elasticsearch, splunk, ...